Can global scripts in typescript have defined implementations?
I've read that what's required for a typescript file to be a global script instead of a module, is to be free of any top level import or export statements.
I realize this is normally used for declarations. But would this also mean I can just define a concrete class in one of these files, without exporting it, and it gets added to the global scope?
Just trying to learn typescript. Have read many answers but none about this specifically

Yes, you can write global scripts that do things. If you write a standalone ts file foo.ts and its contents are just, say, class Foo {}, then TypeScript will compile that to foo.js and assume the Foo class will end up in the global scope. But it's up to your runtime environment to actually run foo.js in global scope. Are you writing stuff for the browser? For node?

Yes, but you’ll want to use the declare global syntax. You can also use export {}; at the bottom of declaration files which in my experience ensures it’s reliably picked up regardless of environment (export an empty object)

In addition to the information in the previous comments… relying on globals has historically been the source of an entire category of software bugs — and exporting/importing values and types within modules addresses that. See, for example, the compiler option isolatedModules. If you are learning TS today, it is useful to understand global behavior, but I encourage you not to prefer it over modules.

@jcalz So it would get compiled, but if my other files don't import foo.js then I suppose it just never gets run? Assuming this is on nodejs, and the entry point is one of the other files. Could I say that in this setup, this global script would only be useful if it had type declarations for informing the TS compilation process?

so in summary tsc would only use the declarations at compile, but node would never run the file so any definitions or side effects in this global script would never execute?

So you're asking specifically about node? Then please tag the question as such. I'm not really a node expert so you'd be looking for someone who knows about node to answer.
